# Elasticsearch malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the elasticsearch client for doing some search query using constant_score and aggregations but it's throwing the exception:

`[parsing_exception] [constant_score] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]`

This is where I'm creating the query and calling the search function:

```
fetchData: function fetchFn(req, res, next) {
    var model = new urlModel();
    util.log('Fetching data from ES::');
    var query = buildAggregateUrl(req.reqData);
    // if (req.reqData['domain']) {
    //     var termFilter = { "term": { "domain": req.reqData.domain } };
    //     query.constant_score.filter.bool.must.push(termFilter);
    // }
    model.search({ query }, function (er, re) {
        if (re) {
            req.sendResult = re;
        }
        next(er);
    });

    function buildAggregateUrl(opts) {
        var query = {
            constant_score: {
                filter: {
                    bool: {
                        must: [{
                            "range": {
                                "timestamp": {
                                    "gte": opts.startTime,
                                    "lte": opts.endTime
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            aggs: {
                success: {
                    scripted_metric: {
                        init_script: "params._agg.succ=0;",
                        map_script: "if(doc.status.value=='success'){params._agg.succ+=1}",
                        combine_script: "return params._agg.succ",
                        reduce_script: "int sum=0;for (a in params._aggs){sum+=a}return sum"
                    }
                },
                failure: {
                    scripted_metric: {
                        init_script: "params._agg.fail=0;",
                        map_script: "if(doc.status.value=='failure'){params._agg.fail+=1}",
                        combine_script: "return params._agg.fail",
                        reduce_script: "int sum=0;for (a in params._aggs){sum+=a}return sum"
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return query;
    }
}

 And this is what the search function looks like:

    es_model.prototype.search = function (opts, cb) {
    var query = {
        index: this.esConfig.index,
        type: this.esConfig.type,
        body: {query:opts.query} 
    };
    console.log('Query ===> ',query);
    this.client.search(query, cb);
}
```

I can't figure out where the problem is with the syntax.I tried wrapping the constant_score key withtin query as well but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply missing a `query` element at the top level:

```
{
    query: {
        constant_score: {
        filter: {
            bool: {
                must: [{
                    "range": {
                        "timestamp": {
                            "gte": opts.startTime,
                            "lte": opts.endTime
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
        }
    },
    aggs: {
        success: {
            scripted_metric: {
                init_script: "params._agg.succ=0;",
                map_script: "if(doc.status.value=='success'){params._agg.succ+=1}",
                combine_script: "return params._agg.succ",
                reduce_script: "int sum=0;for (a in params._aggs){sum+=a}return sum"
            }
        },
        failure: {
            scripted_metric: {
                init_script: "params._agg.fail=0;",
                map_script: "if(doc.status.value=='failure'){params._agg.fail+=1}",
                combine_script: "return params._agg.fail",
                reduce_script: "int sum=0;for (a in params._aggs){sum+=a}return sum"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that your client code should look like this:

```
es_model.prototype.search = function (opts, cb) { 
    var query = { 
        index: this.esConfig.index, 
        type: this.esConfig.type, 
        body: opts.query
    }; 
    this.client.search(query, cb); 
}
```

Comment: I tried that already but failed with this exception:[parsing_exception] no [query] registered for [query]

Comment: Well, you probably need to show some more code as the query is correct as it is.

Comment: Well this is where I'm calling the client's search function:                                    `es_model.prototype.search = function (opts, cb) {
    var query = {
        index: this.esConfig.index,
        type: this.esConfig.type,
        body: { query: opts.query }
    };
    this.client.search(query, cb);
}`                                                                     And this is where I'm calling this wrapper function:                                        model.search({ query },cb);

Comment: Still I'm getting this exception: `[parsing_exception] Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [constant_score].,`

Comment: Well, update your question with the exact code you have now, otherwise we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Your query doesn't look like mine, i.e. you don't have the `query` keyword around `constant_score` + the `body` parameter doesn't look like what I showed you either. Re-read my answer carefully and fix your code accordingly.

Comment: I made the edits suggested by you and your solution worked.Thanks for the help :)